# Pivot 12 Months dynamically backwards from current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

| CustName | Date | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 01/01/2021 | 12 |
| Second | 01/01/2021 | 10 |
| Second | 05/02/2021 | 1 |
| Second | 10/11/2021 | 14 |

I am trying to do a sum of hours per month per customer.

I figured out how to do this using a Pivot such as:

```
SELECT
CustName AS [Customer], ISNULL([January],0) AS [January], ISNULL([February],0) AS [February], ISNULL([March],0) AS [March]
FROM 
(
SELECT
    CustName,
    DATENAME(MONTH, Date) AS [Month],
    RegHrs
FROM TimeEntrySimpleList
) AS Src
PIVOT
(
SUM(Hours)
FOR [Month] IN ([January], [February], [March])
) AS Pvt

select* from TimeEntry
```

This works fine if I want to report say January - December in a static way, only ever showing the months I assign.
But what I want to do is have the last month column (March in my example), and show 12 months from the current backwards in the columns.

I'm guessing I would have to set the current month as a variable? And use it in the pivot .. but I'm not sure how / what to do. Use some sort of calc [month]*12 (reverse)?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: When working with `PIVOT` and trying to dynamically populate and aggregate the columns, dynamic SQL is an option. Have you explored that?

Comment: Is it ok with you if the months are fixed name like `Customer, Mth1, Mth2, Mth3, . . .` You display the actual month name in your client application

Comment: @Squirrel Unfortunately not. The data is being displayed into a grid which displays the column names in the SQL

Comment: in that case, you will need to use dynamic sql query. Check out [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) Or search for dynamic pivot in this site

Comment: Thank you, @Squirrel ! I was afraid of that :)